# Bootstrap 3 same height of images in row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code and I need to have images in row with same height -> they are of the same height:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12" style="padding: 0 10px 0 0;">
   <a href="/shoes/">
     <img src="http://placehold.it/590x350" class="img-responsive" border="0" data-width="590" data-height="350" />
   </a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6" style="padding: 0 10px 0 10px;">
   <a href="/shirts/">
     <img src="http://placehold.it/285x350" class="img-responsive" border="0" data-width="285" data-height="350" />
   </a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6" style="padding: 0 0 0 10px;">
   <a href="/jackets/">
     <img src="http://placehold.it/285x350" class="img-responsive" border="0" data-width="285" data-height="350" />
   </a>
</div>
```

Do you know about some fix for this?

[image]

Comment: You want them with same width, same height or both?

Comment: sorry, I mean same height, not width, my bad..

Comment: It's done, check my post.

Comment: @K.Daniek thanks but I need that padding between images.. Without padding it works fine for me too..

Comment: It's done. Check it out.

Answer (score 2):

Create a class for the img and add a height

```css
.images img{
  height: the height you need it
}
```

```html
<div class="images">
<div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12" style="padding: 0 10px 0 0;">
   <a href="/shoes/">
     <img src="http://placehold.it/590x350" class="img-responsive" border="0" data-width="590" data-height="350" />
   </a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6" style="padding: 0 10px 0 10px;">
   <a href="/shirts/">
     <img src="http://placehold.it/285x350" class="img-responsive" border="0" data-width="285" data-height="350" />
   </a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6" style="padding: 0 0 0 10px;">
   <a href="/jackets/">
     <img src="http://placehold.it/285x350" class="img-responsive" border="0" data-width="285" data-height="350" />
   </a>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Same height, here you go.

```css
img {
  max-height: 100px;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>



  <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12" style="padding: 0 10px 0 0;">
    <a href="/shoes/">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/590x350" class="img-responsive" border="0" data-width="590" data-height="350" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6" style="padding: 0 10px 0 10px;">
    <a href="/shirts/">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/285x350" class="img-responsive" border="0" data-width="285" data-height="350" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6" style="padding: 0 0 0 10px;">
    <a href="/jackets/">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/285x350" class="img-responsive" border="0" data-width="285" data-height="350" />
    </a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you could try doing something like these if you are using bootstrap.

```html
<div class="images">
<div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12" style="padding: 0 15px;">
  <div class="col-xs-12" style="padding:0">
   <a href="/jackets/">
     <img src="http://placehold.it/285x350" class="img-responsive" border="0" data-width="285" data-height="350" />
   </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6" style="padding: 0 15px;">
  <div class="col-xs-12" style="padding:0">
   <a href="/jackets/">
     <img src="http://placehold.it/285x350" class="img-responsive" border="0" data-width="285" data-height="350" />
   </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6" style="padding: 0 15px;">
  <div class="col-xs-12" style="padding:0">
   <a href="/jackets/">
     <img src="http://placehold.it/285x350" class="img-responsive" border="0" data-width="285" data-height="350" />
   </a>
  </div>
</div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need a container and the a row before u start calling bootstrap col-md-3.

[You can learn more about Bootsrap here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic)

One more thing, is not proper to style a html element that has a bootstrap class with your own custom class but you can do somethin like this:

```html
<div class='$any_Bootstrap_css'>
  <div class="wrapper">
    You can the insert your content here like the img tag.
    </div>
  </div>
```

You can always have this inside another wrapper that you can then add your custom class style.